# References to study vector calculus in an intuitive way.

Tags: reference-request, vectors, vector-analysis

I saw lots of questions asking reference for vector calculus book which have some concrete theoretical basis. But I want a book which introduce topics of the calculus of several variable in an intuitive way with geometrical ideas. So please suggest me some good books. The word good may be subjective. But  anyway I need a book which introduce partial derivatives, line integrals and surface integrals geometrically.Thank you.

Comment: As the calculus becomes increasingly abstract and generalized, it becomes harder to find the geometric analogues.  That doesn't mean that mult-variate calculus is without is geometrical representations, but less so.  And they are much harder to sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe me Stewart's multivariable calculus will satisfy all your thirst!!I have studied from that book and it is damn damn good book provides excellent geometric approach and intuitition.Also there are video lectures by one professor Adrian Banner on you tube which are really helpful.There are 15 lectures on multivariable calculus and from lec.$10$,Vector calculus gets started.You will fall in love of his teaching!

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&ei=DqFGWtuQCsHGvgSQvLvYCQ&q=adrian+banner+multivariable+calculus+lec+10&oq=adrian+banner+multivariable+calculus+lec+10&gs_l=psy-ab.3...97725.99764.0.101846.7.7.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.0.0....0.4Plzey0Y7u4#

Answer (score 0):

how about James J. Callahan: Advanced Calculus: a geometric view; Springer.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach which is more physical (and therefore possibly more geometric or visual) is Schey’s “Div, Grad, Curl, and All That.”  YMMV